# Si yo inicializo el constructor con un mensaje string porque me sale este mensaje?

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy aprendiendo hacer arboles en una búsqueda binaria y dentro de una clase puse otra clase en privado con el nombre de "dentro" luego creé un puntero *miRaiz que apunta a la clase "dentro", luego a mi clase "Fuera" en la parte publica hay un método vacío la cual arroja true o false en caso "miRaiz" no sea cero.

Mi pregunta es Porque el valor de "miRaiz" cambia sí mi Constructor recibe un string y sólo por esto el valor de de "miRaiz" cambia. No comprendo porque pasa esto si yo no estoy asiendo cambios en mi puntero "miRaiz".

Gracias por su ayuda aqui mi código:

```
   #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

template <class cualquier>
class Fuera
{
    class dentro
    {
    public:
        cualquier dato;
        dentro *puntDentroDer;
        dentro *puntDentroIzq;
        dentro(): puntDentroDer( 0 ),puntDentroIzq(0){}
        dentro(cualquier elemento):
                    dato(elemento), puntDentroIzq(0),puntDentroDer(0){} 
    };

    typedef dentro *puntDeDentro;

    void presentar(puntDeDentro algo) const;

    /*Atributo*/
    puntDeDentro miRaiz;
public:
    Fuera();
    Fuera(string Hola){cout << Hola;};
    bool vacio() const;

};

template <class cualquier>
inline Fuera<cualquier>::Fuera():miRaiz( 0 ){}

template <class cualquier>
inline bool Fuera<cualquier>::vacio() const
{
    return miRaiz == 0;
}

int main()
{
    Fuera<int> objeto("\nEspero que esto salga bien\n");
    cout <<  "El  Arbol de Sergio " <<  (objeto.vacio() ?  "esta" : "no esta") << " vacio\n " ;
    cout << "\nLendy\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí

```
template <class cualquier>
inline Fuera<cualquier>::Fuera():miRaiz( 0 ){}
```

estás inicializando miRaiz en 0.

Aquí

```
Fuera(string Hola){cout << Hola;};
```

no.

Comment: entonces lo que ud. me dice es que aunque inicialice mi constructor con la 2da opcion (porque hice una por defecto y otra con variable) el valor de "miRaiz" no es que cambia si no que nunca le di un valor.

Comment: @Mucacran Al no inicializar miRaiz en el constructor, va a quedar apuntando a cualquier dirección, la que la casualidad le asigne, puede ser 0 o cualquier otra.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya entendí.